# Jump to line in CSV file

Tags: ios, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

- a'man
- a-bomb
- a-line

just with a around 30.000 entries. So I know the exact number of lines and now I want to jump to a specific line and retrieve its string. 
How can I do this? The CSV parsers I have seen only parse all entries of a file.
I need this for an iOS app, so the programming language is Objective-C. If there is a more elegant and faster solution your are welcome to tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSArray * array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString * string = [array objectAtIndex:10];
```

Or change the separator, but in csv file (Comma Separated Value)